# How to write WHERE IN clause from a dynamic ArrayList for Android SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, where-in

How can i write the where in clause in Android SQLite query?

Function to retrieve a single customer

```
public Cursor getCustomers(int groupId) {
    return db.query(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, new String[] { KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, KEY_NAME}, KEY_GROUP_ID+" = "+groupId, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Function to retrieve a more customers

```
public Cursor getCustomers(ArrayList<Integer> groupIds) {
    // Need to apply SELECT id, name FROM customers WHERE id IN (11, 13, ...18);
    //return db.query(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, new String[] { KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, KEY_NAME}, KEY_GROUP_ID+" = "+groupIds, null, null, null, null);
}
```

The size of the groupId ArrayList is dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return db.query(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, new String[] { KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, KEY_NAME }, KEY_GROUP_ID + " >=" + groupIdsLowLimit + " and " + KEY_GROUP_ID + " <=" + groupIdsUpLimit, null, null, null, null);

String where = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    where = where + KEY_GROUP_ID + " =" + list.get(i).toString() + "";
    if (i != (list.size() - 1))
        where = where + " or";
}

return db.query(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, new String[] { KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, KEY_NAME }, where, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: sorry, id list may be like (11, 103, 6, 100)

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [Android TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) class join method to make a comma separated list of IDs to put in the in clause.

```
String selection = KEY_GROUP_ID + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(", ", groupIds) + ")";
return db.query(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, new String[] { KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, KEY_NAME}, selection, null, null, null, null);
```

BTW if groupIds is a list of primary keys from another table you should be using Longs to store them not Integers otherwise it will overflow when the IDs get large.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something in [@JosephL's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207475/josephl) **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675597/1318946)** as per my study:

I have two **ArrayList** with following values:

**First ArrayList** (in First Column) have duplicate values and **Second ArrayList** (in Second Column) has unique values.

```
=> 67 : 35
=> 67 : 36
=> 70 : 41
=> 70 : 42
```

Printing both after processing as below:

1. First Array : **`"(" + TextUtils.join(",", arrayList1) + ")"`**
2. Second Array : **`"(" + TextUtils.join(",", arrayList2) + ")"`**
3. First Array (Remove Duplicates using `new HashSet<>(arrayList1)`):

   **`"(" + TextUtils.join(",", new HashSet<>(arrayList1)) + ")"`**

   => First Array : (67,67,70,70)

   => Second Array : (35,36,41,42)

   => First Array (Remove Duplicates using `new HashSet<>(arrayList1)`): (67,70)

Hope it will useful. Thanks.